# How to copy multiple files using aws s3 sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to copy multiple files from one folder to another folder using aws s3 sdk java. I can see the method copyObject() provided is for single file.
Below is the code which is provided in documentation.

```
 CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(getBucketName(),
    "srcFolderName" + "/" + key, getBucketName(), "targetFolderName" + "/" + key);
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentDisposition("attachment");
copyObjectRequest.setNewObjectMetadata(metadata);
getS3Client().copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

How can I give multiple files path?

Ex:  Source

1. A/srcFolderName/123/file.txt
2. A/srcFolderName/456/file.txt
3. A/srcFolderName/789/file.txt
4. A/srcFolderName/112/file.txt
5. A/srcFolderName/101/file.txt

Files need to copy are 1,2,5.

After copy

1. A/targetFolderName/123/file.txt
2. A/targetFolderName/456/file.txt
3. A/targetFolderName/101/file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy multiple objects with one API call.

The `CopyObject` API call **will only copy one object**.

You can, however, issue multiple API calls through **multiple threads** so that operations are done in parallel.